Header height - react native / Expo router
I am working on a react native project, using Expo router, to work on the header/ or topNavBar.
in the
<Stack.Screen  name="usage"  options={usageHeader} 
there are differnt way to set the header, either a custom component for the whole header, by using header , or using the navigation feature and then using of headerTitle  and headerLeft  and headerRight. I am using the second approch because I don't have to worry about safe area an so on. But the issue is that I couldn't find a way to increase the height of the header.
headerStyle only accepts backgroundColor.
Is there a olution for this, or am I missing something?
I found an issue about this on gitHub, but i didn't see any solution apart from using header and defining a whole custom component.
https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/10097
headerStyle: { backgroundColor: '#E9FDFF', height: 100, // not doing anything marginTop: 100, // not doing anything paddingTop: 100, // not doing anything },

You can change backgroud and height props with headerStyle. But for headerStyle you cannot change margin or padding props, you can edit title instead.
Example:
<Stack.Screen
  options={{
    headerStyle: {
      height: 300,
      backgroundColor: '#E9FDFF',
    },
    headerTitleStyle: {
      marginTop: 100,
      padding: 100,
    },
  }}
  name="AboutProduct"
  component={AboutProduct}
/>



That only works with @react-navigation/stack. Expo router's stack navigator uses @react-navigation/native-stack under the hood, which doesn't support options like height in headerStyle.
FWIW, setting the height this way does work in other Expo Router navigators like the Drawer. Just not with Stack.

With Expo Router, you can use header option with the <Header /> component and add the props headerStyle
import { Header } from "@react-navigation/elements";
import { Stack } from "expo-router";

    <Stack
      screenOptions={{
          header: ({ options }) => (
            <Header
              {...options}

              headerStyle={{
                height: 100,
                backgroundColor: "red",
              }}
            />
          ),
        }),
      }}
    >
    enter code here
    </Stack>

Source: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/elements/#header
